# DTLS handshake fail on ipv6

Tags: c, openssl, ipv6, dtls

I have a demo code of dtls, it works well with ipv4. but after I modified it for ipv6, it  fails at handshake stage.
The server code like this:

```
SSL_load_error_strings();
SSL_library_init();
SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLSv1_server_method());
if(SSL_CTX_use_certificate_chain_file(ctx, "path/to/crt") !=1)
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

if(SSL_CTX_use_PrivateKey_file(ctx, "path/to/key", SSL_FILETYPE_PEM) != 1)
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);

SSL_CTX_set_verify(ctx, SSL_VERIFY_PEER, verify_cert);
SSL_CTX_set_read_ahead(ctx, 1);
SSL_CTX_set_cookie_generate_cb(ctx, generate_cookie);
SSL_CTX_set_cookie_verify_cb(ctx, verify_cookie);
SSL_CTX_set_cipher_list(ctx, "ALL:NULL:eNULL:aNULL");

int fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
struct sockaddr_in6 server_addr;
memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
server_addr.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
server_addr.sin6_port = htons(MYPORT);
server_addr.sin6_addr = in6addr_any;
int flag = 1;
if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &flag, sizeof(flag)) < 0)
    perror("server reuse addr");

#ifdef SO_REUSEPORT
if (setsockopt(fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &flag, sizeof(flag)) < 0)
    perror("server reuse port");
#endif
if(bind(fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)))
    perror("bind server fd");

BIO *bio = BIO_new_dgram(fd, BIO_NOCLOSE);
SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);

/* Enable cookie exchange */
SSL_set_options(ssl, SSL_OP_COOKIE_EXCHANGE);


fprintf(stderr, "Wait for incoming connections\n");
struct sockaddr_in6 client_addr;
while(1){
    int ret = DTLSv1_listen(ssl, &client_addr);
    if(ret < 0){
        ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
    }
    if(ret > 0)
        break;
}
fprintf(stderr, "Handle client connection\n");
int client_fd = socket(client_addr.sin6_family, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
if (setsockopt(client_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEADDR, &flag, sizeof(flag)) < 0)
    perror("reuse addr");

#ifdef SO_REUSEPORT
if (setsockopt(client_fd, SOL_SOCKET, SO_REUSEPORT, &flag, sizeof(flag)) < 0) 
    perror("reuse port");
#endif
if(bind(client_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)))
    perror("bind client fd");
if(connect(client_fd, (struct sockaddr *)&client_addr, sizeof(client_addr)))
    perror("connect client");
BIO *cbio = SSL_get_rbio(ssl);
BIO_set_fd(cbio, client_fd, BIO_NOCLOSE);
BIO_ctrl(cbio, BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SET_CONNECTED, 0, &client_addr);
fprintf(stderr, "waiting SSL_accept\n");
if(SSL_accept(ssl)!=1){
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
}
fprintf(stderr, "SSL_accept completed\n");
```

and the client code is:

```
SSL_load_error_strings();
SSL_library_init();
SSL_CTX *ctx = SSL_CTX_new(DTLSv1_client_method());
SSL_CTX_set_read_ahead(ctx, 1);

union {
    struct sockaddr_storage ss;
    struct sockaddr_in6 s6;
    struct sockaddr_in s4;
} server_addr;
int fd;
memset(&server_addr, 0, sizeof(server_addr));
if(inet_pton(AF_INET, argv[1], &server_addr.s4.sin_addr) == 1){
    fd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    server_addr.s4.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_addr.s4.sin_port = htons(MYPORT);
}else if(inet_pton(AF_INET6, argv[1], &server_addr.s6.sin6_addr) ==1){
    fd = socket(AF_INET6, SOCK_DGRAM, 0);
    server_addr.s6.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
    server_addr.s6.sin6_port = htons(MYPORT);
}else{
    fprintf(stderr, "Wrong ip format\n");
    return 1;
}
if(connect(fd, (struct sockaddr*)&server_addr, sizeof(server_addr)))
    perror("connect");
BIO *bio = BIO_new_dgram(fd, BIO_NOCLOSE);
BIO_ctrl(bio, BIO_CTRL_DGRAM_SET_CONNECTED, 0, &server_addr);
SSL *ssl = SSL_new(ctx);
SSL_set_bio(ssl, bio, bio);
fprintf(stderr, "waiting SSL_connect\n");
if(SSL_connect(ssl)!=1)
    ERR_print_errors_fp(stderr);
fprintf(stderr, "SSL connected\n");
```

It seems no return in SSL_accept and SSL_connect.
I modified the code by changing sockaddr_in to sockaddr_in6 only.
The openssl version is: 1.0.2h on linux

Also I caught the packages with wireshark:
[image]
[image]

Can somebody tell me what's wrong with the code ?

Comment: DTLS had some problems in 1.0.2 and below. I seem to recall they were discussed on the OpenSSL mailing list and fixed. [OpenSSL Master](http://openssl.org/source/gitrepo.html) should be OK. I don't recall if it was ported back to 1.0.2 and below. I would try Master first and see if it clears the issue. Also, can you use `s_client` and `s_server` to establish a connection?

Comment: @jww I can't find a arg to make s_sever to bind a ipv6 port. And s_client also failed to connect to my server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I add

```
BIO_ctrl_set_connected(bio, 0, &client_addr);
```

after `DTLSv1_listen` in server side solved this problem.